# Auth0 returns error when I am trying to login

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, openid-connect, auth0

I successfully created a new app on Auth0 but I cannot login from my node.js/expressjs app using the `BASE_URL` I provided.

I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQwo4E_B0y8) but when it comes to the part when I request the `/login` page, my app just send me a `{"message": "Internal server error"}`.

my logs show :

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "AggregateError: Issuer.discover() failed.\n    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443\n    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "AggregateError",
        "errorMessage": "Issuer.discover() failed.\n    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443\n    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443",
        "name": "AggregateError",
        "stack": [
            "AggregateError: Issuer.discover() failed.",
            "    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443",
            "    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443",
            "    at Function.discover (/var/task/node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:265:17)",
            "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: AggregateError: Issuer.discover() failed.",
        "    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443",
        "    RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443",
        "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)",
        "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
        "    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"
    ]
}
```

Current config in my `app.js` :

```
app.use(auth({
  authRequired: false,
  auth0Logout:true,
  issuerBaseURL: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL,
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  idpLogout: true,
}))
```

My app is hosted on lambda so instead of entering `localhost:3000`,  my `BASE_URL` is my lambda function base url `https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/`

Did I make something wrong ?

Comment: hey, having the same issue :) did u figure it out ?

Comment: It seems this issue has something to do with compatibility issue with other dependencies. I fixed it by creating a completely new project from scratch and by implementing auth0 first before any other librairies and it finally worked.

Comment: oh, so will try to disable some deps, trial & error
thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my package.json file. Then reinstalled the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still hitting this and getting `OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 404 Not Found` , double and triple check your issuer base url as mentioned [here](https://github.com/auth0/express-openid-connect/issues/309)